# How to test if a remote server support tls1.2 on Mac OS

Tags: macos, openssl

I have googled and find

https://serverfault.com/questions/638691/how-can-i-verify-if-tls-1-2-is-supported-on-a-remote-web-server-from-the-rhel-ce,

the command:

```
openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 -tls1_2
```

does not work on MacOS because of "unknown option -tls1_2" error.

Comment: I realize this is an old thread, but I recently had the same question. Anyone open to installing powershell, which is now supported on OSX, a Linux and Windows can leverage a script I wrote to output the SSL/TLS protocols that the client is able to successfully use to connect to a server using fqdn or ip. I hope this helps someone. https://github.com/TechnologyAnimal/Test-TlsProtocols/blob/master/Test-TlsProtocols.ps1

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You could use `curl` to test it. I believe `curl` is installed with command line tools on OS X.

```
$ curl https://google.com/ --tlsv1.2 --verbose
*   Trying 46.134.192.54...
* Connected to google.com (46.134.192.54) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
* Server certificate: *.google.com
* Server certificate: Google Internet Authority G2
* Server certificate: GeoTrust Global CA
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: google.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
```

Comment: Now, need to replace `--tlsv1.0` with `--tls-max 1.0` to be work.

Answer (score 14):

Thanks to [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32392038/26510) on this page, I wrote this simple script to test a server for TLS 1.0, 1.1, and 1.2 support. This should work on any linux/unix flavor, I suspect, and definitely works on Mac, as that's what I'm using to test it

```
$ tls_test.sh tls1test.salesforce.com
TLS1.2 is supported on tls1test.salesforce.com
TLS1.1 is supported on tls1test.salesforce.com
### TLS1.0 is NOT SUPPORTED on tls1test.salesforce.com ###
```

## tls_test.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

die()
{
  echo "$*"
  exit;
}

# Get server to test, and timeout in seconds
server=$1
timeout_in_seconds=${2:-20}
case "$timeout_in_seconds" in
  ''|*[!0-9]*) die "Your timeout value should be an integer value, not '$2'"
esac

# where to log full responses to
dump_file=${3:-/tmp/__dump_tls_info}
rm -f "$dump_file"

show_help()
{
  me=$(basename "$0")
  info=$(cat <<EOF
  Shows which versions of TLS a server supports.

  usage: $me SERVER {TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS} {DUMP_FILE}

  e.g.  The following are public test servers that demonstrate
  support for various TLS versions.

  $ $me tls1test.salesforce.com       # validate TLS 1.0 is blocked
  $ $me tls-v1-0.badssl.com:1010      # validate only TLS 1.0 enabled
  $ $me tls-v1-1.badssl.com:1011      # validate only TLS 1.1 enabled
  $ $me smtp.gmail.com:465            # validate TLS 1.0+ are all supported

  Note: default timeout in seconds is 20, and it dumps full output to $dump_file
EOF
  )
  echo "$info"
  exit
}

if [ -z "$server" ]; then
  show_help
fi

testTLS()
{
  tls="$1"
  tlsDisplay=${2:-$1}
  if [ -n "$tls" ]; then
    tls_cmd="--tlsv$1"
  else
    tls_cmd=""
  fi

  CMD="curl --max-time "$timeout_in_seconds" -v -I --silent "$tls_cmd" "https://$server/""
  OUT=$($CMD 2>&1)
  CURL_VERSION=$(curl --version)
  OUT_CURL_OLD=$(echo "$OUT" | grep "option --tls" | grep "unknown")
  OUT_TLS=$(echo "$OUT" | grep "topped the pause stream")
  OUT_TLS_HANDSHAKE=$(echo "$OUT" | grep "handshake fail")
  OUT_TIMEOUT=$(echo "$OUT" | grep "onnection timed out after")

  {
    echo 
    echo "#######################################"
    echo "testing TLS$tls is supported on $server"
    echo "curl version: $CURL_VERSION"
    echo "curl location: `which curl`"
    echo "os version: `sw_vers`"
    echo "ran the following:"
    echo "$CMD"
    echo "$OUT"
    echo 
  } >> "$dump_file"

  if [ -n "$OUT_TIMEOUT" ]; then
    echo "connection to $server timed out after $timeout_in_seconds seconds"
  fi
  if [ -n "$OUT_CURL_OLD" ]; then
    echo "Your version of curl is too old, and can't test for TLS $tls support"
    return;
  fi

  if [ -n "$OUT_TLS" ]; then
    echo "### TLS $tlsDisplay is NOT SUPPORTED on $server ###"
  else
    if [ -n "$OUT_TLS_HANDSHAKE" ]; then
      echo "### TLS $tlsDisplay is NOT SUPPORTED on $server ###"
    else
      echo "TLS $tlsDisplay is supported on $server"
    fi
  fi
}

testTLS 1.2
testTLS 1.1
testTLS 1.0
```

Comment: Tried this with google.com and it says `NOT SUPPORTED` for v1.0, v1.1 and v1.2. But when I did a cURL I got `TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256`.

Comment: @Abhilashk - i've updated the script with a local one I had that had some minor changes - for me, it works fine with Google (Says that it supports all tls versions, and tls1test.salesforce.com doesnt)

Comment: Thanks for your time. Tried the updated script, still stays `NOT SUPPORTED` for me - https://imgur.com/a/sZaJmjL

Comment: @Abhilashk - hmmm... i've tried it on 2 computers, and it works for me - can you try again, then dump the output of what you see in the file `/tmp/__dump_tls_info` somewhere online so I can see what you're getting?

Comment: Hmm.... I took a look, and it appears that your output suggests you are only able to do TLS v1.0 connections - maybe your openssl has blocked TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2 ? I'll look closer, fyi

Comment: @Abhilashk - I updated the script, and think it should work. Let me know how it goes!

Comment: Now it's showing `TLS 1.0 is supported on tls1test.salesforce.com` though it's not the case according to https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=tls1test.salesforce.com . Screenshot - https://imgur.com/a/Bw8P8zn

Comment: You're right in that it should fail for tls1 on tls1test.salesforce.com. Your curl must be failing it in a different way than the 3 computers I've tested this on... Don't feel you have to, but if you get a chance, can you post your `/tmp/__dump_tls_info` file, after running this for tls1test.salesforce.com

Comment: https://pastebin.com/M2Le18HK . Really appreciate your patience! Thankyou so much :) Also, what I don't understand is SSL handshake is failing in all 3 conditions. Your thoughts?

Comment: @Abhilashk - strange! not really sure what's up there. I updated the script one more time to add info about your curl version and the curl command being run - maybe there'll be something there... Try again if you like!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179419/discussion-between-brad-parks-and-abhilash-k).

Comment: @BradParks..... In case, if you open for suggestions, this script is giving wrong answer in 2 case - 1. If domain doesn't exists 2. If DNS is not replying and script not able to fetch the IP for the domain.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
nmap --script ssl-cert,ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443,465,993,995 www.google.com
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because **your openssl is old**, which does not have TLSv1.2 updates. Please consider upgrading your openssl then it should work.
I have tested this on my Mac works fine. Similarly now there is TLSv1.3 in the market but I've not upgraded my Openssl to latest so, for `-tls1_3` I get the same error

Comment: You mean `-tls1_3` ,  correct? Your openssl command will likely fail (silently) on a mis-spelling.... .